# Javascript Regex to find a word started with or followed by anything other than a character or digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find names of programming languages in text, I've tried for days to find the correct regex, but I can't find it.
Also running into problems when the language is C++ or C#
I want to match the name of the languages if it starts with or ends with anything other than letters or digits.

```
  reg = new RegExp("\\b[\\+" + language[element] + "] \\b", "gi");
```

Comment: What is `language[element]`? Can you provide code that is self-contained?

Comment: `reg = new RegExp("(?<!\\w)" + language[element].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?!\\w)", "gi");`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, that seems to have worked. The only problem is when it's looking for the C language, it matches with C# and C++ too. What would be the same Regex, but without matching with + and # after?

Comment: Then, what about `reg = new RegExp("(?<!\\S)" + language[element].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?!\\S)", "gi");`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't seem to match a stand-alone C followed by, or . or anything. Is it a way for it to match all symbols other than ++ and #

Comment: So, no `#` and `++` allowed after the lang element? Try `new RegExp("(?<!\\w)" + language[element].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?!\\w|\\+{2}|#)", "gi");` then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It still matches if the C is followed by ++ or #.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/eK79ld/1, it does not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my mistake, it does work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
new RegExp("(?<!\\w)" + language[element].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "(?!\\w|\\+{2}|#)", "gi");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK79ld/1) if `language[element]` holds the `C` text. *Details*:

- `(?<!\w)` -  no word char allowed immediately before the current location
- `C` - a `C` char
- `(?!\w|\+\+|#)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a word char, or `++` or a `#` char immediately to the right of the current location.